# Explicit implementation of property through an abstract class in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

Here's what I am trying to do:

At the top sits an interface:

```
interface IHasPosition
    {
        Position Position
        {
            get;
        }
    }
```

next up, we have an abstract class:

```
abstract class Person : IHasPosition
    {
        public abstract Position Position
        {
            get;
        }
    }
```

Finally, I extend Person:

```
class Instructor : Person
    {
        public override Position Position
        {
            get { return new Position(1, 1); }
        }
    }
```

This compiles just fine. However, I seem to be unable to explicitly define the property Position. Something like this:

```
class Instructor : Person
    {
        public override Position IHasPosition.Position
        {
            get { return new Position(1, 1); }
        }
    }
```

This fails to compile:

```
Error   1   'ConsoleApplication3.Instructor.IHasPosition.Position': virtual or abstract members cannot be private
Error   3   The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item
Error   2   The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item
```

Comment: Why do you want to explicitly implement the interface's property?

Comment: The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item - you are trying to implement it explicitly; The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item - again related to first statement

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?i mean why abstract implementation on base class and private in derived?or do you want public in derived?

Answer (score 3):

`Instructor` is inheriting `Person` and `Instructor.Position` is overriding `Person.Position`.

Since `Person.Position` already implements `IHasPosition.Postion`, so does `Instructor.Position`.

**`Instructor` is a `Person` is a `IHasPosition`.**

Explicit implementation of the interface `IHasPosition.Position` on `Instrcutor` is unnesscessary and, would be misleading.

Lets possit that you do explicitly implement the interface that has already been inherited. On the override it is superfluous, and illegal because its `public`, on another member it creates an ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

There's a syntax error in your code: *explicit interface implementation* can't be *public*.
Technically, you can put it like that:

```
   class Instructor: Person {
     // From Person abstract class
     public override Position Position 
     {
       get { return new Position(1, 1); }
     }

     // Explicit interface implementation
     Position IHasPosition.Position 
     {
       get { ... }
     }
   }
```

But as Jodrell said, it's a *very bad style*.

Comment: +1 for showing you can actually do it. (-1 to anybody who actually does.)

Comment: That still doesn't seem to work. It complains about the containing type not implementing IHasPosition:

Error 'ConsoleApplication3.Instructor.IHasPosition.Position': containing type does not implement interface 'ConsoleApplication3.IHasPosition'